# How can I calculate length contraction using hyperbolic functions?

Tags: special-relativity, geometry

In the image below, the pink line on the $x$ axis is the length contracted measurement correspondent to the $x'$ measurement in the primed reference system. This length (let's call it $l$) equals $x'/cosh(\phi)$. I've been looking at this diagram for hours and understand where all the labels come from. I still can't see how $l = x'/cosh(\phi)$. Can someone show me how this is so, geometrically?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a spacetime diagram with $v/c=(3/5)$.

$$(v/c)=\tanh\phi=\frac{OPP}{ADJ}=\frac{TQ}{OT}=\frac{3}{5}$$

$$\gamma=\cosh\phi=\frac{ADJ}{HYP}=\frac{OT}{OQ}=\frac{5}{4}$$

[image: robphy-RRGP-lengthContraction-triangle]

Consider the shaded triangle $OX'L$.

In Minkowski spacetime geometry, $OX'L$ is a right-triangle with
right-angle at $X'$ since $OX'$ and $LX'$ are perpendicular.

- $LX'$ is parallel to the worldline $OQ$ of the moving frame.
  $OX'$ is the spatial axis of the moving frame.
- $LX'$ is the tangent at $X'$ to the hyperbola centered at $O$, where $OX'$ is a radius.

$\phi$ in $OX'L$ is numerically equal to the rapidity $\phi$ in right-triangle $OTQ$.

*($\phi$ in $OX'L$ is between two spacelike lines... so I don't want to call that a "rapidity". However those spacelike lines are respectively perpendicular to and coplanar with the timelike worldlines in $OTQ$.)*

Thus, in $OX'L$ we have

- hypotenuse $OL$ (since it is opposite the vertex $X'$ with the right-angle)
- adjacent side $OX'$

Thus,
$$\gamma=\cosh\phi=\frac{ADJ}{HYP}=\frac{OX'}{OL}$$
or
$$OL=\frac{OX'}{\cosh\phi}$$

Using numbers,
$$4=\frac{5}{\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}$$
which says that
"4 meters is the apparent length of the moving 5-meter-stick."

---

(By the way, in Minkowski spacetime geometry, $OX'L$ and $OTQ$
are congruent right-triangles.)

Comment: Perfectly clear, as always. I'm really lucky to have you answering all my questions as I struggle to wrap my head around this perspective on relativity. Is there a place where I can find all your papers on the topic? Thanks again!

Comment: @polytheneman Thanks. I'm glad my answers are helpful. Your feedback helps me refine my approaches. "Relativity on Rotated Graph Paper" (AmJPhy 84, 344 (2016) ; https://doi.org/10.1119/1.4943251 and https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1111.7254 and Ch 7 of https://doi.org/10.4324/9781003161721 ) and "Visualizing Proper Time in Special Relativity" ( https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.physics/0505134) and https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/author/robphy/ . See also http://visualrelativity.com/LIGHTCONE/LightClock/ and http://visualrelativity.com .

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Just so I'm clear, $\phi$ is not the rapidity, but half the rapidity, right?

Comment: @polytheneman The rapidity $\phi$ is the Minkowski-angle, the ratio of Minkowski arc-length/Minkowski radius on the hyperbola. The area of the hyperbolic sector is $(\phi/2) r^2$.

Comment: So am I correct in assuming that there's an error in the original diagram I posted? It seems to indicate that the area of the hyperbolic sector is $(ϕ/2)r$ instead of $(ϕ/2)r^2$

Comment: @polytheneman Reasoning with units, the area has to be proportional to a length-squared.